# LXDE, TghtVNC and IceWeasel on Synology NAS

Tags: nas, synology, tightvnc, lxde, iceweasel

I have a DS412+ Synology NAS (Dual Core a 2.13 GHz - 1Go of RAM).

I would like to install the LXDE desktop on it and VNC server to access it.

**Is it possible to install these packages by the command line like on others linux distros ? And how to do it ?**

When accessing the NAS by SSH, it displays this :

```
BusyBox v1.16.1 (2015-06-29 18:12:44 CST) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

DiskStation> help
Built-in commands:
------------------
. : [ [[ alias break cd chdir continue eval exec exit export
false getopts hash help let local printf pwd read readonly return
set shift source test times trap true type ulimit umask unalias
unset wait
```

---

The only thing needed for me on this LXDE is iceweasel browser running 24/7.

**Will this have an impact on performances of the NAS or will it shorten is life or HDDs over time ?** (Since a NAS is, for me, made to store data over the network and not have a browser running on it)

Comment: BTW, I can't think of a reason why LXDE would shorten the life, unless you are using a CLI and SSDs, and you're thinking that the increased activity of a GUI desktop might eat into the SSD life (although my recollection of LXDE is that it isn't very "active").

Comment: @fixer1234 I edited the question, hope it helps to understand the question.

Comment: No I don't know what is "Pineriver H24" and what reference are you talking about ? Yes I need the GUI.

Comment: Sorry, yes I was talking about "24 hours a day" (english is not my primary language). I'll use the browser to access [freebitco.in](https://freebitco.in) and play the "Multiply BTC" I want to run this 27/7 and I can't let my client  computer on all day and night.

Comment: Last thought:  You have two fairly unrelated questions (how to install via command line, and will it impact performance/life).  You might get a better response splitting this into two questions.  BTW, I never would have guessed English isn't your primary language.  You write better than many users for whom English is their native language.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no answer, no one read this anymore or the question is too old
I guess I stumbled into this be cause I need this solution myself, and I found one: docker ... so, I like to share :)

install docker on NAS, then install in it something like Ubuntu, then in Ubuntu you can install everything you wanted (is a very, VERY, basic Ubunu, but with package installing system - apt-get - up and ready), so, you need to install LXDE (I personally prefer icewm, enough functionality and it consumes lower cpu and memory than any other WM, with the same functionality), firefox and tightvncserver, and set up ports so you can connect from outside to that vnc server (5900 is the standard one ...)

also, this solution has improved security be cause Ubuntu will be isolated against main system